# Dockerfile directory location in wondows 8.1

Tags: docker, dockerfile, virtualbox, windows-8.1

I am using Windows 8.1 and i installed Docker Toolbox. In CMD in did, 'docker pull clelange/cc7-cmssw-cvmfs' and it executed without any problem.

When i typed docker info, it shows I have 4 containers and it is not stored in my laptop but on virtualbox. My doubts are: 
1) How do I go to the Docker File directory ? 
2) How do i see the images in these containers? 
3) Can i run make and make docker-push commands here?

When i try running the make command after running docker pull in Docker Quickstart Terminal, it shows an error 'bash: make: command not found' ? How do i resolve this?

Comment: Please wrap the code section in '` .. `' quotes.

Comment: `bash: make: command not found` means that you doesn't have a GNU make package installed. Probably you are running it from a wrong place. A good sign of 'right place' is the presense of file named `Makefile`.

Comment: Please describe your goal in more details. What do you want to achieve by running all those commands?

Comment: I want to develop a CMSSW Development area. For that after i do ``` docker pull clelange/cc7-cmssw-cvmfs``` , I need to go into the Dockerfile location and then enter ``` make``` command. But since I am using Windows 8.1, I have installed docker toolbox and the above commands I am running in Docker Quickstart terminal.  The bash errors are shown in this terminal

Comment: I am not able to install make in Docker Quickstart terminal.